# client ssl_connect function return Bad Certificate

Tags: authentication, ssl, openssl

my client's ssl_connect() return the Bad Certificate errno, what are the possible cases for this situation. I am using non-blocking socket. Thanks.

Comment: A "Bad Certificate errno" is caused by a bad certificate. The actual error returned should actually have more details than just "bad" so please have a look at the actual error returned by `SSL_get_error`. And it does not matter if the socket is blocking or not for this kind of error.

Comment: Do you mean `SSL_connect`, an OpenSSL routine which returns only -1/0/+1 and sets error info for a certificate in the error queue not `errno` -- or `ssl_connect` which isn't OpenSSL at all? @SteffenUllrich+ `SSL_get_error` returns only the broad class `ERROR_SSL` or `ERROR_SYSCALL` -- or for nonblocking `WANT_x` which aren't really errors but aren't success either. To get details from error queue use `ERR_*` and usually the most informative is `ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout)`. Alternatively use commandline `openssl s_client` with appropriate options and look at its display.